# Erlang with multiple client shells - spawned process hangs in 'io' module

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

working through Joe's book, got stuck on Chapter 12 exercise 1. That exercise is asking one to write a function *start(AnAtom,Fun)* that would register *AnAtom* as *spawn(Fun)*. I've decided to try something seemingly easier - took the chapter's finished 'area_server' module, and modified it's start/0 function like this:

```
start() ->
    Pid = spawn(ex1, loop, []),
    io:format("Spawned ~p~n",[Pid]),
    register(area, Pid).
```

so in place of a process executing the arbitrary Fun, I am registering the 'loop', which is a function in the area_server module doing all the work:

```
loop() ->
    receive
        {From, {rectangle, Width, Ht}} ->
            io:format("Computing for rectangle...~n"),
            From ! {self(), Width*Ht},
            loop();
        {From, {square, Side}} ->
            io:format("Computing for square...~n"),
            From ! {self(), Side*Side},
            loop();
        {From, Other} ->
            io:format("lolwut?~n"),
            From ! {self(), {error, Other}},
            loop()
    end.
```

It seems to be working just fine:

```
1> c("ex1.erl").
{ok,ex1}
2> ex1:start(). 
Spawned <0.68.0>
true
3> 
3> area ! {self(), hi}.
lolwut?
{<0.61.0>,hi}
4> flush().
Shell got {<0.68.0>,{error,hi}}
ok
5> area ! {self(), {square, 7}}.
Computing for square...
{<0.61.0>,{square,7}}
6> flush().
Shell got {<0.68.0>,49}
ok
```

Thing went bad when I've tried to test that multiple processes can talk to the registered "server". **(CTRL-G, s, c 2)**

I'm in a new shell, running alongside the first - but the moment I send a message from this new shell to my 'area' registered process, something nasty happens - when querying process_info(whereis(area)), process moves from this state:

```
 {current_function,{ex1,loop,0}},
 {initial_call,{ex1,loop,0}},
```

to this one:

```
 {current_function,{io,execute_request,2}},
 {initial_call,{ex1,loop,0}},
```

while the message queue starts to grow, messages not getting processed. Hanging in module *io*, huh! Something is blocked on the io operations? Apparently the process is moved from my ex1:loop/0 into io:execute_request/2 (whatever that is)... are my silly prints causing the problem?

Comment: Hm I wonder if it's the same problem as is discussed here: https://elixirforum.com/t/erlang-elixir-interactive-shell-jobs-get-stuck-when-printing-to-output/8023/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processes are doing what you expect *with the exception of handling who has control over STDOUT* at what moment. And yes, this can cause weird seeming behaviors in the shell.

So let's try something like this *without* any IO commands that are implied to go to STDOUT and see what happens. Below is a shell session where I define a loop that accumulates messages until I ask it to send me the messages it has accumulated. We can see from this example (which does not get hung up on who is allowed to talk to the single output resource) that the processes behave as expected.

One thing to take note of is that *you do not need multiple shells to talk to or from multiple processes*.

Note the return value of `flush/0` in the shell -- it is a special shell command that dumps the shell's mailbox to STDOUT.

```
Eshell V9.0  (abort with ^G)
1> Loop = 
1>   fun L(History) ->
1>     receive
1>       halt ->
1>         exit(normal);
1>       {Sender, history} ->
1>         Sender ! History,
1>         L([]);
1>       Message ->
1>         NewHistory = [Message | History],
1>         L(NewHistory)
1>     end
1>   end.
#Fun<erl_eval.30.87737649>
2> {Pid1, Ref1} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> Loop([]) end).
{<0.64.0>,#Ref<0.1663562856.2369257474.102541>}
3> {Pid2, Ref2} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> Loop([]) end).
{<0.66.0>,#Ref<0.1663562856.2369257474.102546>}
4> Pid1 ! "blah".
"blah"
5> Pid1 ! "blee".
"blee"
6> Pid1 ! {self(), history}.
{<0.61.0>,history}
7> flush().
Shell got ["blee","blah"]
ok
8> Pid1 ! "Message from shell 1". 
"Message from shell 1"
9> Pid2 ! "Message from shell 1".
"Message from shell 1"
10> 
User switch command
 --> s
 --> j
   1  {shell,start,[init]}
   2* {shell,start,[]}
 --> c 2
Eshell V9.0  (abort with ^G)
1> Shell1_Pid1 = pid(0,64,0).
<0.64.0>
2> Shell1_Pid2 = pid(0,66,0).
<0.66.0>
3> Shell1_Pid1 ! "Message from shell 2".
"Message from shell 2"
4> Shell1_Pid2 ! "Another message from shell 2".
"Another message from shell 2"
5> Shell1_Pid1 ! {self(), history}.
{<0.77.0>,history}
6> flush().
Shell got ["Message from shell 2","Message from shell 1"]
ok
7> 
User switch command
 --> c 1

11> Pid2 ! {self(), history}.
{<0.61.0>,history}
12> flush().
Shell got ["Another message from shell 2","Message from shell 1"]
ok
```

Comment: Thanks mate; I am going to study your example now to understand your point; I am somewhat surprised, however, about this io module thing. Why would anyone be handing at all? As in, I've sent messages to the server from Shell 1. Server printed to STDOUT. Then I've sent another bunch from Shell 2, but this time the server didn't print [to the other shell's output stream?]. Why? I am not conflicting with the old print, we're seconds apart. Is something still holding onto some lock? But why?

Comment: Alright, I was able to replicate your example, mutatis mutandis. Indeed, everything is pointing at the io module being the culprit; I find this behavior is very suspicious. Is there a reason why you're using spawn_monitor, not simple spawn? I'm just learning Erlang/OTP, and trying to keep things as simple as possible =)

Comment: @alexakarpov On monitors: Having orphaned processes (that lack a clear termination condition) is a Bad Thing, so that is partly out of habit. I had considered showing how termination sends messages to the monitoring process, which is *only* shell 1 in this case, but figured the example would just go too long. As for STDOUT handling, the shell *is* a process of its own, so when you switch to shell 2 you spawn a new process and hand over control of the STDOUT resource. *That really shouldn't break, though*: there is some IO resource handling business in the background that has not been sorted.

Comment: @alexakarpov One thing to note about the handling of STDOUT -- this is the only case I've ever encountered it: jumping around in different local shells in the same terminal. In practice this has actually never been a problem, which is probably why it has been slow to identify and slow to fix. *This behavior may also be intentional*: Imagine connecting to 3 remote systems at the same time in the days before multi-session terminal emulators. Your screen could be a blur of unintelligible activity quite quickly.

Comment: have you seen the other comment with a link I posted earlier, btw?

Comment: @alexakarpov I saw it. I'm still not quite sure whether bug or feature, though. Probably a bug that results in the feature's apparent intended behavior 90% of the time -- but is actually a bug. I don't have an hour to read the related sources and it has never caused an actual problem for me (lack of a peer distributed source repository swarm, however, *is* a problem for me, which is why I'm releasing one this week...). TBH, the signal::noise ratio in the Elixir world (and syntax) causes me to avoid it in general.